# Anaconda Navigator: cannot manage Channels

Tags: python, anaconda, navigator

I have anaconda3 installed and python works OK the problem is when I come to want to add a channel it seems to be stuck forever "collecting sources...". The screen looks like this. There is no error or "not responding" message. How can I fix it? I would prefer not to have to re-install Anaconda if it could be avoided.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem received no responses, so I concluded the only option was to re-install. I removed Anaconda, cleaned up the registry of Anaconda and Python references then re-installed Anaconda.